# Question on numbers whose remainder is more than half of the divisor

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I started the question by writing this:

$$
\color{Blue}{x\mod n \geq \frac n 2} \\
x\mod 2 \geq 1 \\ 
x\mod 3 \geq 1.5 \approx 2\\ 
\huge\dots \\
\Downarrow\\ 
\color{DarkRed}{x\mod \{2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\} \geq \{1,1.5\approx 1,2,2.5\approx 2,3,3.5\approx 3,4,4.5\approx 4,5\}\Rightarrow \\ x\mod \{2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\} \geq \{1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5\}}\\
\\ \\
$$
Afterwards I basically just wrote the equation out in English.

```
So x had to be:
- An odd number.
- At least 1 more than a multiple of 3
- At least 2 more than a multiple of 4 & 5, or 20
- At least 3 more than a multiple of 6 & 7, or 42
- At least 4 more than a multiple of 8 & 9, or 72
- At least 5 more than a multiple of 10
```

But I don't really now how to go from here. I tried to find a case where some of the cases deny some others but I can't seem to...

**Edit:**
The question:

> Is there a number below 1000 whose remainder when dividing by the numbers 2-10 inclusive is greater than the divisor

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: oh sorry i will put the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to classify the integers $x$ such that the representative of $x\bmod n$ in the set $\{0,\dots,n-1\}$ is always at least $n/2$ for every $n\in \{2,\dots,10\}$.

Clearly the solutions will all be $\bmod lcm(1,2,3,\dots,10) = 2520$

We first try to find congruence necessities $\bmod$ prime powers.
$x$ must be $1\bmod 2$, must be $2$ or $3\bmod 4$ and must be $5,6,7$ or $8\bmod 8$. It follows that $x$ must be $7\bmod 8$.

$x$ must be $2\bmod 3$ and must be $5,6,7$ or $8\bmod 9$. This implies it must be $5$ or $8\bmod 9$.

$x$ must be $3$ or $4\bmod 5$

$x$ must be $4,5$ or $6\bmod 7$

If these equivalence relations are met then the only possible conditions which can fail are those pertaining to $6$ and $10$.

Notice that if $x$ is odd and $x$ is $2\bmod 3$ then $x$ is $5\bmod 6$ and therefore the equivalence relation with $6$ is met.

Notice that if $x$ is odd and $x$ is $3\bmod 5$ then $x$ is $3\bmod 10$ which is a problem. However if $x$ is $4\bmod 5$ and $x$ is odd then $x$ is $9\bmod 10$ which is fine. So $x$ must be $4\bmod 5$.

In conclusion the condition is equivalent to the following congruences:

$x$ is $7 \bmod 8$

$x$ is $5$ or $8 \bmod 9$

$x$ is $4 \bmod 5$

$x$ is $4,5$ or $6\bmod 7$.

We conclude there are $6$ solutions $\bmod 2520$, and we can find them using the Chinese remainder theorem.

Comment: do you mean when the set is $\{2,\dots,10\}$?

Comment: oh yes sorry :)

Comment: Oh ok, the problem then becomes different. I will solve it .

Comment: Thank you so much :)

Comment: Done ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: thanks so much! could you please remind me the meaning of$\mod {}$, since I don't quite understand some of the ways you have used it?

Comment: what is tjh? ${}{}$

Comment: sorry --- typo!

Comment: We say $x$ is $a\bmod n$ if $x-a$ is a multiple of $n$.

Comment: oh ok thank you

Comment: What is the Chinese Remainder theorem? (I'm so uninformed)

Comment: It is a theorem that allows you to find solutions to systems of equivalence relations.

Comment: I will look it up now